# How to get dict key value format using Jinja2 in ansible using debug or set fact module

Tags: json, list, ansible, jinja2

I have following output

```
    TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
    ok: [1.1.1.1] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "DESCRIP": "server-abc",
            "PORT": "Po3",
            "PROTOCOL": "up",
            "STATUS": "up"
        },
        {
            "DESCRIP": "Leaf-1",
            "PORT": "Po4",
            "PROTOCOL": "up",
            "STATUS": "up"
        },
        {
            "DESCRIP": "server-xyz",
            "PORT": "Po1",
            "PROTOCOL": "up",
            "STATUS": "up"
        },  
        {
            "DESCRIP": "Leaf-2",
            "PORT": "Po2",
            "PROTOCOL": "up",
            "STATUS": "up"
        }             
    ]
}
```

i want to get/print only blocks which contains "Leaf" in DESCRIP and "Po" in PORT to do this i have below debug with jinj2

```
 - debug:
    msg: >-
           {%- for item in output.parsed -%}
           {%- if ('Leaf' in item.DESCRIP) and ('Po' in item.PORT) -%}
             "DESCRIP": {{item.DESCRIP}},
             "PORT": {{item.PORT}}
           {%- endif -%}
           {%- endfor -%}
```

i am getting below output printing everything in single line:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [10.2.4.1] => {
    "msg": "\"DESCRIP\": Leaf-1,\n  \"PORT\": Po4\"\"DESCRIP\": Leaf-2,\n  \"PORT\": Po2"
}
```

what i want is dict key value format/json format. like below:

```
[{
    "DESCRIP": "Leaf-1",
    "PORT": "Po4",
},
{
    "DESCRIP": "Leaf-2",
    "PORT": "Po2",
} ]
```

How/what to modify in my code debug msg section to get above output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this, would be to `set_fact` with `when` condition.

In the below example, we create a new variable `serv_list` (initially empty list), then append the `DESCRIP` and `PORT` when the criteria matches.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        serv_list: '{{ serv_list | default([]) + [ { "DESCRIP": item.DESCRIP, "PORT": item.PORT } ] }}'
      loop: "{{ output.parsed }}"
      when:
        - item.DESCRIP is search('Leaf')
        - item.PORT is search('Po')

    - debug:
        var: serv_list
```

Produces:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "serv_list": [
        {
            "DESCRIP": "Leaf-1",
            "PORT": "Po4"
        },
        {
            "DESCRIP": "Leaf-2",
            "PORT": "Po2"
        }
    ]
}
```